# How to hide the 'server' parameter in the apache2 http response header?

Tags: security, http, ubuntu, apache2

My question is posed in the title. But I ask also, instead of hiding it, isn't it possible to replace it by a custom value? Maybe over php or by editing the apache2 config?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use mod_security for Apache, there is a directive called `SecServerSignature` it allows you to change the value of the `Server` header.

Another way would be to edit the the source code :)

Comment: I hope I can trust this project ;) Thank you!